# Change Route In APISIX Dashboard

Tags: wso2-api-manager, apache-apisix

i want to change incoming route to another route to destination.for example:

incoming -->    /api/login/*
outgoing -->    /api/uathenticate/*

every where i see this config:

[image]

Comment: Is what you're looking to rewrite the URL after processing the request? Have you checked `proxy-rewrite` plugin? https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/plugins/proxy-rewrite/

Answer (score 0):

In the URL **Regexp** you have correctly the **source pattern**:

```
^/api/login/(.*)
```

Put the **target format** of the URL into the **Template** field:

> /api/authenticate/$1

That is all what needs to be done to rewrite the URL.